# How to get the date of another member?

Tags: discord.js

So what I was trying to do is get the date of another member:

```
if (member) {
   const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
   message.channel.send(`The date of ${memberTarget} is: ${memberTarget.currentDate.toLocaleString()}`).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}));
}
```

Everything is fine except this part:

```
${memberTarget.currentDate.toLocaleString()}
```

`.toLocaleString()` returns `of undefined`
and `memberTarget.currentDate` does not exist

The full code is:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'date',
    description: "date command",
    execute(client, message, args) {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const member = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (!args[0]){ 
                message.channel.send(`The date is ${currentDate.toLocaleString()}`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
        } else if (member) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
            message.channel.send(`The date of ${memberTarget} is: ${memberTarget.currentDate.toLocaleString()}`).then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 5000}));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What data are you trying to get? What would `currentDate` be?

Comment: I think OP wants to get a member's local time. I don't think it's implemented so there is no way to know that. Probably ask them their timezone and store that somewhere :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know!